# How to customize bootstrap pagination in Django?

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

[image: how to reduce the no displayed in the pagination in the image there are 12 page no displayed whereas I just want 3 page no to be displayed only]

This is the default code for Django pagination:

```
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% with bpurl=bootstrap_pagination_url|default:"" %}

    <ul class="{{ pagination_css_classes }}">

        <li class="prev page-item{% if current_page == 1 %} disabled{% endif %}">
            <a class="page-link" href="{% if current_page == 1 %}#{% else %}{% bootstrap_url_replace_param bpurl parameter_name 1 %}{% endif %}">
                &laquo;
            </a>
        </li>

        {% if pages_back %}
            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="{% bootstrap_url_replace_param bpurl parameter_name pages_back %}">&hellip;</a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}

        {% for p in pages_shown %}
            <li class="page-item{% if current_page == p %} active{% endif %}">
                <a class="page-link" href="{% if current_page == p %}#{% else %}{% bootstrap_url_replace_param bpurl parameter_name p %}{% endif %}">
                    {{ p  }}
                </a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}

        {% if pages_forward %}
            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="{% bootstrap_url_replace_param bpurl parameter_name pages_forward %}">&hellip;</a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}

        <li class="last page-item{% if current_page == num_pages %} disabled{% endif %}">
            <a class="page-link" href="{% if current_page == num_pages %}#{% else %}{% bootstrap_url_replace_param bpurl parameter_name num_pages %}{% endif %}">
                &raquo;
            </a>
        </li>

    </ul>

{% endwith %}
```

So, where should I change the code to display less number of pages. The above code was retrieved from the default code of Django-bootstrap4 pagination 
**Like displaying in this pattern :**
[image]

Comment: please provide more details. Are you using this ? https://github.com/zostera/django-bootstrap4

Comment: I am using: https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap4/